# Iterating through hashes inside an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a stored procedure that returns the following hashes inside of a single array:

```
@cars = [{"make"=>"honda"}, {"color"=>"black"}, {"make"=>"acura"}, {"color"=>"red"}]
```

How would I iterate through each of these so that I can correctly put them into tables. Resulting in:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>honda</td>
    <td>black</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>acura</td>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your data structure is bizarre, wouldn't `[{"make"=>"honda", "color"=>"black"}, {"make"=>"acura", "color"=>"red"}]`, where each element of the array represents a car/row, make more sense?

Comment: The data structure is what I have to work with. So I need to make this work. Any usable advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the format of the data in ruby:

```
@good_cars = @cars.each_slice(2).map { |a,b| a.merge(b) }
# returns [{"make"=>"honda", "color"=>"black"}, {"make"=>"acura", "color"=>"red"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
<% @cars.each_slice(2) do |hash1, hash2| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= hash1['make'] %></td>
    <td><%= hash2['color'] %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```